# Is it possible to use IBM watson-intu and Choregraphe (Nao/Pepper) together

Tags: pepper, project-intu, intu

I would like to know if it is possible to create behaviors (using the tablet and using motors) in Choregraphe for Pepper, and call them from intu? 
Or is there a way to use native function of Naoqi in intu directly?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about intu, but if you can call method from naoqi objects, then it's easy to install choregraphe behaviors on your robots, then you can trigger them using ALBehaviorManager. Is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should [write a Qi Service](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/libqi/guide/py-service.html?highlight=service) and run it on the robot. Qi Services (formerly ALModules) registered in NAOqi's Service Directory can be called remotely using [libQi in a client](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/dev/libqi/guide/py-client.html) (formerly ALProxy).

I don't know IBM Watson Intu, but if you can write a client using jointly libQi and Watson IBM Intu, I think you can easily bridge from one to the other.